# editActionsForRowAtIndexPath - how to close the slider after the action completed

Tags: swift, tableview

What is the way to close the slider after tweet action completed?

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
         let tweet = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Normal, title: "Tweet") { action, index in
         println("tweet")
    }
         let done = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Done") { action, index in
         println("done")
    }
    return [tweet, done]
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When your action is completed or when you switch from `Edit mode` can use this called on your `tableView`:

`self.tableView.setEditing(Bool, animated: Bool)`

as suggested by @Craig.Pearce

Comment: Do I need to implement this inside editActionsForRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: Yes, as I writed above, you need to do this after your action is completed.

Answer (score 2):

I don't have the reputation to comment, but to update the answer by @ciccioska, it should be...

`tableView.setEditing(false, animated: Bool)`